# How to directly complete org-mode tags with helm?

Tags: helm, completion, org-tags

When using `org-set-tags` in org-mode headings, the somewhat clunky `*Org tags*` selection buffer is shown by default. I always press <kbd>tab</kbd> in order to switch to `helm-mode-org-set-tags`, which lets me choose from the list of defined tags with the usual fuzzy matching.

Is there a way to arrive at `helm-mode-org-set-tags` without detour?

Answer (score 1):

The latest `helm-org` version currently published to melpa links to this [GitHub revision](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-org/tree/b7a18dfc17e8b933956d61d68c435eee03a96c24).

The README contains the following snippet in the configuration section that worked for me

```
(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(org-capture . helm-org-completing-read-tags))
(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(org-set-tags . helm-org-completing-read-tags))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, unfortunately. It still shows the `*Org tags*` selection buffer when executing `org-set-tags-command`, but not the helm completion buffer with all predefined tags. I'm using `org-mode` v9.4.2 and `helm-org` v20200311.633.

Comment: @Timm, sorry it seems like I mixed up the question then. Was looking for completion solution when using org-roam and using `helm-org` + the above configuration worked for me for `org-roam-tag-add`. Just now saw, that you were referring to `org-set-tags`.